# Reprinted Cell Text into an UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Into the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of an `UITableViewController` class I am using the next code to show a cell that contains an `UITextView`.

Sometimes when I scroll the table that contains the cell and then I scroll the cell `UITextView`, it shows the cell text reprinted (as if there were two `UITextView` objects, instead of one, into the cell).

What can I do to solve this problem?

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.contentView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
                textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
textView.editable = NO;
textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
textView.text = self.description;

[cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
[textView release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UITableView reuses its cells to increase scrolling performance. Whenever a cell is being reused, you are adding a new text view to the cell (although one is already there).

You should move the creation of the text view (and adding it to the cell) into the `if (cell == nil)` block. Inside this block, also give the text view a unique `tag` and use this `tag` property to access the text view from outside the block. See Apple's table view sample code for examples of this pattern, it is being used a lot.